# How similar are the Regular expressions engines for PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, Perl, etc?

Tags: php, regex

Are regular expressions the same for PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, Perl, and so on? If so, is there a chart or tutorial that explains regular expressions?

Comment: +1 Good question, @php. Asking this just saved you some potential frustration in the future! Welcome to Stack Overflow, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there often are subtle differences in supported features (mostly of the pretty advanced kind<sup>1</sup>). For example, JavaScript regular expressions don't have lookbehind. PHP uses either POSIX extended regular expressions or PCRE (Perl-compatible regex), which are close to Perl's feature-set. In fact, Perl is probably the ancestor of many advanced features in today's regular expression engines.

As for [tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [comparisons](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) the site http://regular-expressions.info is a very good resource.

Once you got used to writing and applying them it often is helpful to just quickly try out things. I have found a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) to be quite handy; I usually use Windows PowerShell but Ruby or Python are also pretty popular.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks, [Dancrumb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261122/dancrumb).

Comment: +1 http://regularexpressions.info is a god-send. One of the best sites to learn RegEx's that I've found.

Comment: +1 for the answer; but I'd add that the differences are usually in the *advanced* features of regular expressions. regularexpressions.info will help you understand what's advanced and what's basic.

Comment: @Dan: Agreed. However, I've also seen things like lazy quantifiers not work (Notepad++ ...) which I consider pretty basic. But yes, the usual greedy quantifiers, string literals, character classes and alternatives are probably supported by pretty much any implementation, including `findstr` on Windows :-)

Answer (score 0):

In theory regular expression is a language for pattern matching.But there are little differences from language to language . My advice is use a tool like [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) to building/learning regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent write-up of Perl regular expressions compared to "classic", POSIX and GNU grep in Chapter 3 of the book "Minimal Perl" by Tim Maher. And I think it's a good read for any of them, not just Perl.

And what do you know, "Sample Chapter 3" is available as a download from this page: [Minimal Perl book](http://manning.com/maher/)!